# ClassNotFoundException for commons-lang3 when deploying WAR to Wildfly 14

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

We're developing an application which uses:

- Wildfly 14
- Java EE 7

The code compiles successfully and the WARs are packaged. However upon deploying the WARs into Wildfly I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils from [Module \"deployment.projectTitle.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
```

Other WARs which also use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` are deployed successfully.

There are two locations where this library is set in the `pom.xml`.

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to provided. Commons is not in the classpath of your application because you told Maven that you would provide it. Is much like compile, but you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime, probably WildFly does not have it.

Comment: As @Pulszar also recommends: Changing the scope to `compile` does work. Even removing it completely does work. However I'm puzzled because Wildfly 14 *does contain* the JAR under:

`modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/commons/lang3/main`
`commons-lang3-3.6.jar`

Comment: @RobertStrauch AFAIK, that will only be available to an application if you explicitly depend on that module in your application descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to change the scope to compile. From  `<scope>provided</scope>` to  `<scope>compile</scope>`

This way you will include in your war the library. I think inside of the Wildfly is not provided and that can be the problem.